# Sorting arrays and in output getting extra first line of random symbols

Tags: c++, sorting

I wrote a program where program sorts people by the each person time, and if time is the same, program sorts by the name alphabetically. Everything works fine, just I am getting extra first line full of random symbols. I of course can write if function and say not to show that first line, but is it good thing to do?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct people {
  string full_name;
  int h;
  int min;
  int sec;
};
bool comp(const people &p1, const people &p2) {
  return (p1.min < p2.min || p1.min == p2.min && p1.sec < p2.sec ||
          p1.min == p2.min && p1.sec == p2.sec && p1.full_name < p2.full_name);
}

int main() {
  int time;
  string fullnamechange[30];
  people peo[30];

  cin >> time;
  for (int i = 0; i < time; i++) {
    getline(cin, peo[i].full_name); // taking everything into a string
    fullnamechange[i] = peo[i].full_name;
    fullnamechange[i].erase(fullnamechange[i].begin(),
                            fullnamechange[i].end() - 8);
    peo[i].h = atoi(fullnamechange[i].c_str());
    fullnamechange[i].erase(fullnamechange[i].begin(),
                            fullnamechange[i].end() -
                                5); // changing time in string to int
    peo[i].min = atoi(fullnamechange[i].c_str());
    fullnamechange[i].erase(fullnamechange[i].begin(),
                            fullnamechange[i].end() - 2);
    peo[i].sec = atoi(fullnamechange[i].c_str());
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < time; i++) { // erasing time from string
    peo[i].full_name.erase(peo[i].full_name.begin() + 20,
                           peo[i].full_name.end());
  }
  sort(peo, peo + time, comp);
  cout << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < time; i++) {
    cout << peo[i].full_name << " " << peo[i].min << " " << peo[i].sec << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

/*
input for example:
6
Petras A. Petraitis    0 20 00
Jurgis Jurgutis        0 12 59
Romas Jonas            0 15 12
Zigmas Nosis           0 23 9
Rimas Senasis          0 15 12

output I get:
 em3╣Mg n Ç         0 0      //random numbers I get
Jurgis Jurgutis      12 59
Rimas Senasis        15 12
Romas Jonas          15 12
Petras A. Petraitis  20 0
Zigmas Nosis         23 9 */
```

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly if you adopted an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and apply it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it.

Comment: Test your program with `time = 1` see what will happen. You need to use `cin.ignore()` before `getline` to eat new line characters, which was bufferd by `cin >> test`.

Comment: @rafix07 oh yes, it really works. But after I wrote this line why in output in every line there is no first letter?

Comment: Call `cin.ignore` only once, after `cin >> test` and before entering into *for* loop. Calling ignore before every getline was my mistake in previous comment

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!